# Can libusb be build using GNU GCC compiler?

Tags: c++, c, com, gnu, libusb

I am trying to start using libusb for communication via COM port ( **EDIT**: for my Rs232 device), on windows 10 x64 only. My IDE is Code:blocks. I have a couple of questions:

I downloaded libusb [from their website](https://libusb.info/) (latest windows binaries)

[image: libusb download]

But I noticed there is a [libusb-win32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/) ''version'' of it in sourceforge. It says

> "libusb-win32 is a port of libusb-0.1 under Windows"

1. What does this mean, and should I use the "latest windows binaries" version or the "libusb-win32" version?

<s>Also, the Readme file from their website (the 'libusb windows binaries' one) has instructions for compiling in Visual Studio and Mingw and there are files for Visual studio and Mingw only.</s>

2. Does this means I cannot compile the libusb it in GNU GCC compiler?

EDIT: the question 2) is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252750/13294095

Comment: What environment are you developing on?

Comment: Windows 10, Code:blocks. Let me add this detail on the question.

Comment: Then the Windows binaries are all you need.  You do not need to build them, just include the .dll and .lib in project.

Comment: Your question is not clear though, are you interested in compiling the source into your own binaries, or is your interest more pointed toward using existing binaries to start coding?

Comment: My second comment was not exactly correct.  If you just want to use the provided binaries from the download, then include .lib and .h into your project, and place the .dll where it will be visible.  For development I usually just place the .dll in the same directory as the .exe that will use it.  Later it should go into C:\Windows\sysWOW64 if `32bit`, or C:\Windows\System32 for `64bit`

Comment: @ryyker So the libusb-win32 are pre-compiled files for windows? I did not figure that out. Thanks. Their website just said "libusb-win32 is a port of the USB library libusb 0.1 " but they did not say that its just pre-compiled binaries, I could not understand what "port"meant there.

Comment: Yes, they are compatible with windows.   Look in the examples directory for testlibusb.c.  If you have the .lib and .h, installed in project, and .dll is visible, this file should compile without a problem.

Comment: libusb is for USB devices, COM ports are RS-232 devices, so I'm not sure on how you'll use libusb for COM port access. But libusb 1.0.24 builds perfectly fine with MinGW-w64 in MSYS2 shell using `./configure --disable-udev && make`

Comment: @BrechtSanders I am using a RS-232 device (I want to communicate with my microcontroller). I will add this detail to the question as well

Comment: Are the com ports you refer to virtual or based on a physical UART device.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios if you want serial RS-232 comunication, than why don't you use something like the library at http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/ instead?

Comment: @ryyker I have a physical uart device after the Rs232, I my MCU. I use the Rs-232 to translate from UART to USB protocol. -Even though I do not know what "Virtual com port" is.

Comment: @BrechtSanders I will check it out, thanks

Comment: If you have a device that when you plug it into your PC via a USB port, it instantiates a COM port, then that device does have a UART.  The device  must also have driver that upon connecting to the PC is installed, and results in establishing the serial port you can see in device manager (under ports)  Read about [USB serial driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-driver-installation-based-on-compatible-ids) for some background.

Comment: I see. Then as I replied above, my device has UART and its not virtual com port.

Comment: Well, your device may have a UART, but when you plug it into a PC via a USB port, a virtual serial port is created via a driver on the PC... _"When the USB to serial adapter is connected to the computer via the USB port the driver on the computer creates a virtual COM port which shows up in Device Manager on Windows, "_  Read [more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_adapter). (under Architecture)

Comment: Hmm I see.  libusb is used to talk to USB, so I might not be able to use it to talk to COM port.

Comment: ...So, it is still unclear to me why you need to use libusb.  i.e. if when you plug your device into the PC, you can see a port that has been created in Device Manager, then all the work is done.  Your code can use [a C serial port library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24698145/645128) to open a port and send/receive serial messages, etc.  However,  if you are _developing_ the device with the UART to work on a Windows PC via a USB port, then yes, you need to create a driver.  Maybe then libUSB is for you.

Comment: After seeing the comments here I wont use libusb, and you are right, I need to communicate with COM port, not USB, so libusb is useless in this scenario. I will use a C serial port library. Thank you everyone. Some of you should shall post a complete answer based on the question and the comments so I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I am trying to start using libusb for communication via COM port ( EDIT: for my Rs232 device), on windows 10 x64 only"*

If you have a device that when you plug it into your PC via a USB port, it instantiates a COM port, then that device does have a UART. The device must also have driver that upon connecting to the PC is installed, and results in establishing the serial port you can see in device manager (under ports) Read about [USB serial driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-driver-installation-based-on-compatible-ids) for some background.

> *"I have a physical uart device after the Rs232, I my MCU. I use the Rs-232 to translate from UART to USB protocol. -Even though I do not
> know what "Virtual com port" is."*

Your device may have a UART, but when you plug it into a PC via a USB port, a [virtual serial port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_COM_port) is created via a driver on the PC... *"When the USB to serial adapter is connected to the computer via the USB port the driver on the computer creates a virtual COM port which shows up in Device Manager on Windows"*... Read [more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_adapter). (under Architecture)

In short, if when you plug your device into the PC, you can see a port that has been created in Device Manager, then all the work is done. Your application code can incorporate a [C serial port library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24698145/645128) to open a port and send/receive serial messages, etc. However, if you are developing the device with the UART to work on a Windows PC via a USB port, then yes, you need to create a driver. Maybe then libUSB is for you.